# raspberry pi android communication

Tags: android, python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, wifi

So I have a passive infrared sensor(PIR) connected to my pi3, and right now, whenever something gets close to the sensor, an LED attached to the Pi turns on or off. I wanted to get some ideas from you guys on how to do this on an android app. So when my hand gets close to the sensor, an app on the android shows a green circle, and when I take my hand away from the sensor it shows red.

I'm pretty new to both Pi and Android Studio, so I mainly want someone to point me in the right direction, not write my code for me. Just need to know what I should study and look into. Is a server better? Is Bluetooth easier? It's for a university project and time's a big constraint, so I just want the easiest way to do it for now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about using a bluetooth module on the pi and send the values to your android device. I would actually have your code run as a background service and send a push notification with a different color icon for when movement is detected.

Comment: Do I need something for that or just code? Like I mean should I buy something physical for it? Cause I'm heading to the store soon for something now

Comment: To be honest Im not sure. I use a arduino nano on a breadvoard with a bluetooth module. Then the bluetooth module can send data in continuous mode to any connected device etc. I know how the android code works, not so much the electronics.

Comment: I've managed to sorta figure out connecting my phone to the pi, I was curious, what sort of code did you write to make the Arduino send info to the android app?

Comment: @Bardio, I can share the repo with you here :) https://github.com/julian-labuschagne/RGB_LED_Bluetooth_Arduino/blob/master/RGB_LED_Bluetooth_Arduino.ino . The bluetooth has its own library as well.